# Как перевести отсчёты с файла wav в секунды

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, я построил график звукового сигнала wav во временной области (который представлен ниже), но вместо секунд выводятся отсчёты, как отсчёты представить в виде секунд?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код, который позволяет получить частоту дискретизации с wav-файла, а дальше не пойму как в секунды перевести отсчёты

```
   `// Метод, получающий частоту дискретизации
    public void GetSampleRate(string waveFile)
    {
        //Читаем данные
        using (var fs = new FileStream(waveFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                RiffId = br.ReadBytes(4);
                Size = br.ReadUInt32();
                WavId = br.ReadBytes(4);
                FmtId = br.ReadBytes(4);
                FmtSize = br.ReadUInt32();
                Format = br.ReadUInt16();
                Channels = br.ReadUInt16();
                SampleRate = br.ReadUInt32();
                BytePerSec = br.ReadUInt32();
                BlockSize = br.ReadUInt16();
                Bit = br.ReadUInt16();
                DataId = br.ReadBytes(4);
                DataSize = br.ReadUInt32();

                // Читаем канал
                ReadChannel(br);
            }
        }
    } `
```

Comment: Частота дискретизации это поле `nSamplesPerSec` в структуре `WAVEFORMAT`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757712(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной `SampleRate` находится число сэмплов в секунду. Соответственно время для сэмпла `sample_number` будет:

```
var time = sample_number / SampleRate;
```

Тут `time` будет целочисленным. Если нужны доли секунды:

```
var time = 1f * sample_number / SampleRate;
```

Comment: А `sample_count` это я так понял номер отсчёта делим на частоту дискретизации?

Comment: Нет, ```sample_count``` это и есть номер отсчёта. Только я его неудачно назвал, лучше ```sample_number```.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно же сделать так? Я считываю данные с wav-файла и записываю их в массив data, дальше же можно сделать так, чтобы определённой секунде соответствовала определённая амплитуда, я вот так решил написать: `for(int n = 0; n < data.Length; n++)`
            {
                var time =  n / SampleRate;
            }

Comment: n в данном случае я решил представить как номер отсчёта, массива data, то есть индекс массива это номер отсчёта, а значение индекса амплитуда и дальше я хотел бы время в виде переменной time представить на графике по оси x

Comment: Я не совсем понял вопрос, если честно. Амплитуда меняется с частотой дискретизации, если нужно просто время в секундах для отображения на графике, то да, ```var time = n / SampleRate;```, только нужно учитывать, что тут ```time``` будет в целочисленных секундах. И не забывайте, что размер сэмпла бывает разный, он находится в ```BlockSize```.

Comment: Понял, я просто хочу автоматизировать получение номера отсчёта, у меня файл имеет размер отсчётов 661500 и получение номера отсчёта я хотел бы автоматизировать, дальше в переменной time вычислить время и передать эту информацию в метод, где осуществляется построение графика

Comment: получается я так понял, что переменная time должна хранить информацию тоже в массиве, так как там не одно значение ж будет

Comment: в ней я хотел бы хранить просто секунды var time = 1f*n / wav.SampleRate;``

Comment: амплитуды в массиве data хранятся, а секунды хотел бы хранить в переменной time

Comment: Тогда массив для времени это не самый лучший выбор. Я бы завёл структуру, где хранил бы номер сэмпла и его данные. По номеру сэмпла всегда можно получить его время. И давай найдём какой альтернативный чат, чтобы не спамить на SO.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57531/discussion-between-andrey273-and-uladzimir-palekh).